# Hide Add to cart for certain categories

Tags: php, woocommerce

I need to remove the Add to cart button along with the quantity entry field for a certain category of products (e.g. legal services) from everywhere (from all pages). In doing so, leave those elements that add other plugins in the area where the add to cart button is located.

I would use this code:

```
// Disable products from categories (a, b, c) from being purchased no matter what
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'set_catalog_mode_on_for_category', 10, 2 );
 
function set_catalog_mode_on_for_category( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
 
 if( has_term( array( 'a', 'b', 'c' ), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
    return false;
  }
 
  return $is_purchasable;
}

// Hide 'Add To Cart' for variable products, but keep product variations visible
function remove_add_to_cart(){
    if( has_term( array( 'a', 'b', 'c' ), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
    

       remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation','woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
}
}
```

but then the other buttons that are added by other plugins to the ‘add to cart’ area disappear along with the button ‘add to cart’.

Then I thought maybe I could use this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wp_replace_add_to_cart_btn', 31 );
function wp_replace_add_to_cart_btn() {
    if( has_term( array( 'a', 'b', 'c' ), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
                
?>
    <style>div.quantity,.single_add_to_cart_button{display:none}</style>
    <style>div.quantity,.qty{display:none}</style>

    <script>jQuery(document).ready(function($){$('div.quantity,.single_add_to_cart_button'),remove()})</script>
    <script>jQuery(document).ready(function($){$('div.quantity,.qty'),remove()})</script>
<?php

}
}
```

But in this case the cart button disappears only on the product page, while remaining on the archive product page (shop page).

Another disadvantage of this method is that it doesn't work on pages where products from other categories are displayed in the Related Products widget, where the add to cart button is allowed.

Could you help refine the last code or provide a better solution.

I would not like to use plugins that turn the store into a catalog, as they have too much code and then the pages take 1-2 seconds longer to load. Please any help with the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that this solution works with errors.
I will leave it here as the wrong solution, and below I will post a new answer with the correct solution.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'wp_replace_add_to_cart_btn', 31 );

function wp_replace_add_to_cart_btn() {
    
    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    if (has_term( array( 'a', 'b', 'c' ), 'product_cat', get_the_id ())) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
    
        ?>
    <style>div.quantity,.single_add_to_cart_button{display:none}</style>
    <style>div.quantity,.qty{display:none}</style>

    <script>jQuery(document).ready(function($){$('div.quantity,.single_add_to_cart_button'),remove()})</script>
    <script>jQuery(document).ready(function($){$('div.quantity,.qty'),remove()})</script>
<?php

    }
    
    else{
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
    }
    
}
}
```

Comment: This code still doesn't work. It also removes buttons in other categories.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might be worth looking into the woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link filter

Comment: @jtowell Yes, I'm already looking into it and will probably publish it if the result is successful, thanks

Comment: @jtowell, I've added a new answer below, please tell me what you think of it?

Answer (score 0):

This is an improved code of this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/70434889/16275280

This code does the following:
Removing the 'Add to cart' and 'Quantity' buttons from a single item page of a certain category.
Renaming loop 'Add to cart' button to 'View product' on the Shop page, Archive Product page and in the Related Products widget.

Perhaps the only thing I missed here is changing the tooltip text for the button. Unfortunately, I haven't figured out a way yet.

```
/**
 * Replace 'Add to cart' button to link on Shop Page and Archive Pages if is Simple Product
 */

function my_replacing_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {

    $categories = array( 'a', 'r', 'w' );
    
    if (has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', get_the_id() ) ) {
    
        if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
            $button_text = __("View product", "woocommerce");
            $button = '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
            }
        }

    return $button;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'my_replacing_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Remove Add to Cart button from product description of product if is product category (for all product types)
 */

function my_replace_add_to_cart_btn() {
    global $product;
    
    $categories = array( 'a', 'r', 'w' );

        if (has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', get_the_id() ) ) {
        
        ?>
            //Remove 'Add_to_cart' button and 'Quantity' input box with CSS 
            <style>div.quantity,.qty{display:none}</style>
            <style>div.quantity,.single_add_to_cart_button{display:none}</style>
            
            // Remove 'Add_to_cart' button and 'Quantity' input box, restrict user use inspect element in browser
            <script>jQuery(document).ready(function($){$('div.quantity,.qty').remove();})</script>
            <script>jQuery(document).ready(function($){$('div.quantity,.single_add_to_cart_button').remove();})</script>
        <?php
        }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_replace_add_to_cart_btn', 31 );
```

Comment: @LoicTheAztec please check the new way to remove the add to cart button, thanks